# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class

Tags: android-layout, android-intent

When i click imgPlayGame -> Open new activity -> Error
My Main:

```
ImageView imgPlayGame;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.start_game);

        AddEvents();
    }
```

My Events:

```
public void AddEvents(){
    imgPlayGame=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPlayGame);

    //repeat imgPlayGame
    Start_Repeat_ImgPlayGame();

    imgPlayGame.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            StartGame();
        }
    });
}
```

Animation Drawable:

```
public void Start_Repeat_ImgPlayGame(){
    imgPlayGame.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play_anim_repeat);
    animationDrawable= (AnimationDrawable) imgPlayGame.getBackground();     
    animationDrawable.start();      
}
```

Open new activity:

```
protected void StartGame() {
    Intent select_level= new Intent(StartGameActivity.this, SelectLevelActivity.class);
    startActivity(select_level);
}
```

Class play_anim_repeat:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_2"
        android:duration="300"
        >
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_3"
        android:duration="300">
    </item>
     <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_play_4"
        android:duration="300">
    </item>

</animation-list>
```

Error:

> > 11-30 16:14:16.476: E/dalvikvm-heap(11347): Out of memory on a 30025744-byte allocation. 11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):
> >     FATAL EXCEPTION: main 11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):
> >     Process: com.thoai.leminh.huntervsfruit, PID: 11347 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347): java.lang.RuntimeException:
> >     Unable to start activity
> >     ComponentInfo{com.thoai.leminh.huntervsfruit/com.thoai.leminh.huntervsfruit.EasyLevelActivity}:
> >     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error
> >     inflating class  11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):
> >       at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157) 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
> >     Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class  11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2010) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     com.thoai.leminh.huntervsfruit.EasyLevelActivity.onCreate(EasyLevelActivity.java:20)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  ... 11 more 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347): Caused by:
> >     java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    ... 23 more 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347): Caused by:
> >     java.lang.OutOfMemoryError 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3024) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    at
> >     android.view.View.(View.java:3694) 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at android.view.View.(View.java:3624)
> >     11-30 16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.view.ViewGroup.(ViewGroup.java:474) 11-30 16:14:16.491:
> >     E/AndroidRuntime(11347):  at
> >     android.widget.RelativeLayout.(RelativeLayout.java:236) 11-30
> >     16:14:16.491: E/AndroidRuntime(11347):    ... 26 more

Comment: add your EasyLevelActivity.onCreate code

Comment: public class EasyLevelActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  //fullscreen
  requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

  setContentView(R.layout.easy_level);
 }
}

Comment: could you also add your easy_level layout

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgound_easy" >
</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image @drawable/backgound_easy is probably is too large. Try to use another one

http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html